# Keeping CSS properties (font size, line height, border etc) in ratio

Tags: php, html, css, math

Looking for some maths help.

I have designs in a database for t shirt graphics. These are simple quotes in helvetica where the users can choose the font size and line height before saving them.

I am trying to display them on the homepage in a grid, but have an issue with ratios.

They are saved in the database with the css property values, and then I just loop through them and define their styles inline:

```
<div class="design-canvas" id="canvas-size-{{ $order->canvas_size }}" style="height: auto; float: left;">

  <div class="designText"
     style="font-size: {{ $order->font_size }}px; line-height: {{ $order->line_height }}px; border: {{ $order->border }}">
    {{ $order->design_text }}
  </div>

</div>
```

This works fine, but the canvas-size ID represents a selector which has a fixed width. Either 300px or 600px depending on what the user chose.

How can I display these and give them instead e.g. 25% width of the container, but then work out what the font-size etc should be to keep them looking as they were designed?

E.g:

Design 1: 300px, 28px font size, 24px line height.

When its 30% on a large screen I want the word wrap and line height etc to look exactly the same as if it was on a tablet / mobile etc.

On mobile I would like to display them at 100% width, but keep them looking the same.

Comment: Call me crazy, but this seems impossible to troubleshoot without some sort of Fiddle or visuals to look at it.

Comment: And to take a guess...  the answer is to probably use `em` for the text.

Comment: As soon as I posted I realised how open this question is without pictures etc so just knocking one up now.

Comment: @SeanStopnik Offhand, I would say that the answer is to use `em` for **eveything** here.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah I would agree...  I am typically not a fan of `em`'s...  I personally prefer using `px` for text because I like to know exactly how it'll render, but in this case, `em`'s are the obvious proper choice.

Comment: As expressed by most comments, em has solved my issues and made it simpler than first thought!